# ListView in fragment get lost when changing to another tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an activity with `ActionBar` and `tabs`. Each tab is representing one fragment, all run inside the only activity.

I have a Spinner and a ListView inside the first `fragment`. When item selected in Spinner, ListView's data is modified and shown correctly.

The problem occurs when I select second tab, do something there and navigating back to the first tab. After that `ListView` is not updating when item selected on Spinner.

**RouteFragment:**

```
public class RouteFragment extends FragmentBase {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route, container, false);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) fragView.findViewById(R.id.route_list);
        ArrayAdapter<Route> routeListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Route>(this.getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                this.adapter.getRouteList());
        spinner.setAdapter(routeListAdapter);


        long routeId = ((Route) spinner.getSelectedItem()).Id;

        ListView lv = (ListView) fragView.findViewById(R.id.client_list);
        final ClientAdapter clientListAdapter = new ClientAdapter(this.getActivity(), 
                R.layout.route_listview,
                this.adapter.getClientList(routeId));
        lv.setAdapter(clientListAdapter);


        routeListAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener(lv));

        return fragView;
    }
}
```

**RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener:**

```
public class RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;

    public RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener(ListView fragView) {
        this.lv = fragView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Route route = (Route) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        android.util.Log.v("Salesman", "selected route id: " + route.Id);
        android.util.Log.v("Salesman", "selected route name: " + route.Name);


        ClientAdapter clientAdapter = (ClientAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

        Log.v("Salesman", "before clear: " + clientAdapter.getCount() + "");

        clientAdapter.clear();

        Log.v("Salesman", "after clear: " + clientAdapter.getCount() + "");

        List<Client> clientList = DataAdapter.getInstance(Main.getContext())
        .getClientList(route.Id);

        Log.v("Salesman", "raw from DB" + clientList.size() + "");

        clientAdapter.addAll(clientList);

        Log.v("Salesman", "after addAll()"  +  clientAdapter.getCount() + "");
        clientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**TabListener:**

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private FragmentBase mFragment;

    public TabListener(FragmentBase fragment) {
        this.mFragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, mFragment, mFragment.getName());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        android.util.Log.v("Salesman", "reselected");
    }

}
```

List `clientList`, which I get from database, is not empty, I have checked that, as you can see in the code. However, ListView is empty and not reacting and remains empty.

I guess the point is that I am losing my ListView somewher  but I just don't understand where.

There is a one thing also: that issue occurs only when I'm moving from one tab to another. When I'm moving to another activity inside my app and then moving back, I still can see the listview (it's no empty) and can update it.

Could you please point?

Answer (score 2):

I think this occurs on handling fragment transaction after their state changed,

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout,fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout,fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

and then,

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

**Edited...** RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener

```
public class RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private ListView lv;

public RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener(ListView fragView) {
    this.lv = fragView;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
 if(lv!=null)
 {
    Route route = (Route) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    android.util.Log.v("Salesman", "selected route id: " + route.Id);
    android.util.Log.v("Salesman", "selected route name: " + route.Name);


    ClientAdapter clientAdapter = (ClientAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
   if(clientAdapter !=null)
   {
    Log.v("Salesman", "before clear: " + clientAdapter.getCount() + "");

    clientAdapter.clear();

    Log.v("Salesman", "after clear: " + clientAdapter.getCount() + "");

    List<Client> clientList = DataAdapter.getInstance(Main.getContext())
    .getClientList(route.Id);

    Log.v("Salesman", "raw from DB" + clientList.size() + "");

    clientAdapter.addAll(clientList);

    Log.v("Salesman", "after addAll()"  +  clientAdapter.getCount() + "");
    clientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   else
   {
      ClientAdapter clientAdapter = = new ClientAdapter(this.getActivity(), 
            R.layout.route_listview,
            this.adapter.getClientList(routeId));
      List<Client> clientList = DataAdapter.getInstance(Main.getContext())
      .getClientList(route.Id);
      clientAdapter.clear();
      clientAdapter.addAll(clientList);
      lv.setAdapter(clientListAdapter);
   }
 }
 else
 {
      lv=(ListView)getActivity.findViewById(R.id.route_list);
      ClientAdapter clientAdapter = = new ClientAdapter(this.getActivity(), 
            R.layout.route_listview,
            this.adapter.getClientList(routeId));
      List<Client> clientList = DataAdapter.getInstance(Main.getContext())
      .getClientList(route.Id);
      clientAdapter.clear();
      clientAdapter.addAll(clientList);
      lv.setAdapter(clientListAdapter);
 }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

Comment: could you please also point where i should insert that codes? my guess is:tablistener.ontabselected?

Comment: how to handle your fragment transaction, please add/edit that code into your question.And also check is possible to click on listview

Comment: it is possible, i even have an onclick listener for list view

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand what modifications you have done.Also, you have provided code for modified ```OnItemSelected``` implementation, which doesn't have ```getActivity``` and many other methods. Could you please suggest why it is not working and ground your codes with some references? Besides, regarding checking ```lv``` member, if it is null or not, and if yes, then do ```findViewById(viewId)```, I used to find ```lv``` myself in the RouteSpinnerItemSelectedListener.java, after that way not working I just passed the working (as I thought) object. So it won't work either.